# checksum validation error

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

> Downloaded images failed checksum validation

I tried to install Ubuntu on a Nexus 7. I have tried several times in the last month. I followed all directions to the letter, and went through all the troubleshooting steps. I Re-downloaded the Ubuntu Core Nexus 7 installer, but I still *always* get the above notice.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the full output of the operation along with the command you run?